# SVN checkout automation realm password bypass

Tags: powershell, svn

I'm trying to automate a SVN checkout within Powershell so there are no prompts:

```
svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username foo --password bar checkout https://www.whatever.net/svn/something
```

But I get the error message:

> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://www.whatever.net/svn/something'
>       svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

If I do it manually (w/ prompt) it asks me for a realm password and the rest of the data, and after that I can checkout no problem. I am doing this on a Windows 10 Azure VM.

I suspect this is due to realm login - how do I automate this/bypass it with Powershell scripts?

Comment: Which svn client are you using?

Comment: tortoise svn, does it matter? I use the CLI part of it.

Comment: Do you run those commands as different users? Did you try to run the command 1:1 as your own user?

Comment: I ran them as the only, admin user of the machine; and I ran them remotely from another VM via Invoke-Command, with same results. 
Again - I managed to do it manually (with prompt).

Comment: I think you just need to add `--no-auth-cache ` to your command.

Comment: Nope, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The command I've posted was fine. What was the problem was the certification of the Visual SVN server. It used a self signed cert, and that was no good. Changed it to a signed certificate and now it works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following code to checkout a Tortoise SVN repository.

```
#Download a local copy of the SVN Repository
#Wait for command to finish before moving forward
$SVNDownloadJob = Start-Job {TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\SVN_Repo" /closeonend:1 | Out-Null} 
Wait-Job $SVNDownloadJob
Receive-Job $SVNDownloadJob
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: I have to checkout; 
Lets say I do this, how do I accept the certificate and checkout? 

`PS C:\Users\testAdmin> $test = Start-Job {TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /path:"C:/Test" /url:"https://www.whatever.net/svn/something"}`